# mySQL C Connector building on ARM

Tags: mysql, gcc, ubuntu, compilation, arm

I have built the mySQL C Connector as per the instructions on the mySQL website [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-c-building.html), on an ARM computer running Ubuntu 10.  I then copied the built headers and libraries, with correct system links, to the paths specified by `mysql_config --cflags` and `mysql_config --libs`.  So, I have the following output from `my_sql_config --cflags --libs`:

```
-I/usr/local/include
-L/usr/local/lib -lmysql -lpthread
```

and the following directory trees:

```
/usr/local/include:
atomic        hash.h      my_aes.h        my_base.h      my_dbug.h     my_list.h                my_pthread.h     my_trie.h     mysql.h          mysys               sha2.h             t_ctype.h    waiting_threads.h
base64.h      keycache.h  my_alarm.h      my_bit.h       my_dir.h      my_md5.h         my_stacktrace.h  my_uctype.h   mysql_com.h      mysys_err.h         sql_common.h       thr_alarm.h  wqueue.h
config-win.h  lf.h        my_alloc.h      my_bitmap.h    my_getopt.h   my_net.h         my_sys.h         my_vle.h      mysql_time.h     queues.h            sslopt-case.h      thr_lock.h
decimal.h     m_ctype.h   my_atomic.h     my_charsets.h  my_global.h   my_no_pthread.h  my_time.h        my_xml.h      mysql_version.h  service_versions.h  sslopt-longopts.h  typelib.h
errmsg.h      m_string.h  my_attribute.h  my_config.h    my_libwrap.h  my_nosys.h       my_tree.h        myisampack.h  mysqld_error.h   sha1.h              sslopt-vars.h      violite.h

/usr/local/lib:
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Oct 21 10:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root     4096 Oct 21 09:38 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       14 Oct 21 10:12 libmysql.so -> libmysql.so.16
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       18 Oct 21 10:11 libmysql.so.16 -> libmysql.so.16.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2156350 Oct 21 09:56 libmysql.so.16.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2539588 Oct 21 09:56 libmysqlclient.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       11 Oct 21 10:12 libmysqlclient.so -> libmysql.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       11 Oct 21 10:13 libmysqlclient_r.so -> libmysql.so
```

Now, when I try to staticlly compile something, using something like this:

```
gcc -static -o hello_world $(mysql_config --cflags) hello_world.c $(mysql_config --libs)
```

I get an error message as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysql
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Would anyone have any idea as to why my linker cannot find the library when it is in the correct spot and was built on the same platform?  Thanks beforehand.

EDIT: When I run the same compile command without the static flag, the complile works OK, however, at runtime I get a `error while loading shared libraries: libmysql.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`  Does anyone know why that may be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are linking statically against `libmysql.a` but you do not have such a library available.

Libraries with the suffix `.so` are dynamic libraries and libraries with the suffix `.a` are static libraries.

If you create a similar symbolic link which you have for the dynamic library, it will probably work:

```
ln -s libmysqlclient.a /usr/local/lib/libmysql.a
```

Comment: Well, you're right, when I do this, I can link to the library. However, now I get a ton of compile issues from the library itself.  Interestingly, if I DON'T statically link, I still get a `error while loading shared libraries: libmysql.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` at runtime.  Any ideas on that issue?

Comment: You need to run `/sbin/ldconfig -v` if you have not done so after putting the dynamic libraries in place. It will update the cache which contains information about dynamic library mappings. You can run `/sbin/ldconfig -p` to see what mappings currently exist.

Comment: Ah! That worked perfectly. Silly me, forgetting about the dynamic library mapping cache :P  Thanks!